# Is "The World is Yours" copyrighted?

Tags: copyright

There's a videogame called The World Is Yours.

Is that copyrighted? can I use it in my game I'm making? (not in the title).

Not giving much information about my game, it will be about finding pieces of a code and when the pieces are collected the code is "The World is Yours"

Also, is there any way I can check if something is copyrighted?

Comment: Are you just using the phrase "The World is Yours?" or are you using pieces of code OR stories from the video game "The World is Yours"?

Comment: just using the phrase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Ideas are not copyrightable.  It's the presentation of an idea that is.  As I have said before in other questions you don't owe one red cent for saying "Baby Oh" in normal context to Justin Bieber because he got famous for saying it.  It's the presentation of the idea.  If you are just using those words and no aspect of the rest of the work, you're good.  Take a look at things like common episode titles on TV.  Lotta wedding episodes titled along the poem "Something old something new"

Answer (score 1):

All software is protected by copyright laws unless it has a creative commons or other open source license.

Comment: so, the question is can I use the phrase the world is yours in a videogame

Comment: @Lestat A four word ordinary English phase is probably not entitled to copyright, at least standing alone without other elements (font, sound effects, etc.) that combined with the words are distinctively a part of the other game.